# Python - How many Default Modules loaded

Tags: python, linux, module

I need to know, When i run My python over terminal by default how many module are loaded with it which i do not have to import to use, which modules i can directly use ??
My System Env is Ubuntu 11.04
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> dir(__builtins__)
```

This  will give you a long list of the [built in functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html). 
As Matt pointed, you'll have to import the rest before you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

Any part of standard library which is not labeled as **built-in** (e.g. `file` class, `set` class, `locals` function, etc.) resides in some external module that should be imported prior to usage. This includes seemingly "basic" modules too, such as `sys` or `math`.

If you are unsure about particular function, look up the built-ins list here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Any modules you wish to use from the standard library must be imported before you can use them.